# How to change menu sandwich to 'X' on mobile screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am not a bootstrap or css or front end guy. I been trying to look for help online for two days no luck, I have the following navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-captum navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">

            <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar top-bar"</span>
                <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <!-- Branding Image -->
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                {{--<span class="company-name">{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</span>/--}}
                <img src="{{asset('/public/images/logo-captum.png')}}" class="logo">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">

            <!-- User Profile Navbar -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-user-profile">

                <!-- Authentication Links -->
                @if (!session()->has('status'))
                    <li><a href="{{ route('login') }}" class="btn btn-default btn-login">Logga in</a></li>

                @else
                    <li>
                        <a href="//captum.provideit.se/kundservice/" target="_blank">
                            <i class="icon-custom icon-custom-message pull-left"></i>
                            Kontakta kundservice
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ route('profile') }}">
                            <i class="icon-custom icon-custom-lock pull-left"></i>
                            {{ $customer['firstName'].str_repeat('&nbsp;',1).$customer['lastName'] }}
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                           class="btn btn-default btn-login" style="margin-left: 5px;"
                           onclick="event.preventDefault();document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                            Logga ut
                        </a>

                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST"
                              style="display: none;">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                        </form>
                    </li>
                @endif
            </ul>


        </div>

    </div>
</nav>
```

So when I shrink to phone screen I get a sandwich menu like this 
[image]

Is there any way to make this menu on mobile look like this :Basically convert sandwich to 'X' and make it menu full screen centered items.

[image]

Would be very appreciated if I could get any help

Answer (score 0):

You can just Replace the

```
<span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
```

with a glyphicon:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

Here is a working fiddle example using the bootstrap 3.3.7 navbar example:
https://jsfiddle.net/ozjrhjtj/

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery (you can do this animation also without it) in your project you can try this way by adding a class to the button and managing the animation with css.

```js
var button = document.getElementById('theButton');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    button.classList.toggle('active'); // or whatever your active class is
});
```

```css
.navbar-toggle {
  padding: 6px;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar{
  width: 28px;
  height: 2px;
  background: gray;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  display: block;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar:last-of-type{
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navbar-toggle.active .icon-bar.top-bar{
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(6px, 6px)
}
.navbar-toggle.active .icon-bar.middle-bar{
  opacity: 0; 
}
.navbar-toggle.active .icon-bar.bottom-bar{
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(5px, -5px)
}
```

```html
<button id="theButton" type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
            </button>
```

**UPDATE**
I removed jquery from the script and toggled the class with pure javascript.

Comment: what if I do not use jquery ? only when the screen its shrinked ?

Comment: @trace_le i removed jquery but what do you mean with your second question?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that anyone can help you with your particular problem here if you don't provide CSS, at least for the button in question.

However, I would suggest using [Jonathan Suh's ready-made "hamburger" solution](https://jonsuh.com/hamburgers/). You only need to include a single CSS file, choose an animation and write a simple JavaScript to toggle the `is-active` class.

```js
$('.hamburger').click(function(){
 $(this).toggleClass("is-active");
  // Toggle your menu here
  // $('#menu').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
button {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hamburgers/0.9.1/hamburgers.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button class="hamburger hamburger--collapse" type="button">
  <span class="hamburger-box">
    <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
  </span>
</button>
```